# Limit each element in "IN" operator Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE skill_id IN (2,3,4)
```

But I want to limit each of these elements to random 5 rows.
Something like

```
 SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE skill_id IN (2 LIMIT 3 LIMIT 4 LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are expecting here... what rows are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting 5 rows each with skill_id = 2, 3 and 4 respectively.

Comment: The only way I can think of would be separate queries for each skill_id joined with `UNION ALL`

Comment: Suppose there are 29 skill_id

Comment: Step 1: Number rows in RANDOM order Step 2: SELECT top 5 from each group.